# How to send cookies with pyqt webkit?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4, qtwebkit

I am currently trying to implement a web scraper in python with the pyqt bindings.  The site that I am trying to access requires authentication. After logging in through their javascript call, I can see the session cookie in the cookie jar but when making additional requests, no cookies seem to be sent when inspecting the requests.  Is there something that needs to be set for qtwebkit to send cookies?

Comment: How do you make the additional requests ?

Comment: After logging in, the page redirects to the user page which should display account specific information but the page still behaves as if no login occurred.  I have also tried logging into the site using another [browser](http://i-miss-erin.blogspot.com/2009/03/write-web-browser-by-python.html) implemented with pyqt but the same behavior occurs.